# Setting users' username and password in mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, iis-7.5, versioning, tortoisehg

I am a newbie to Mercurial. I am using Mercuraial hg server 2.3.1 on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7). I followed the [this tutorial](http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/02/24/running-a-mercurial-server-on-iis-7-5-windows-server-2008-r2) (I used the latest version of python(Python 2.7) and mercurial(2.3.1)) . It is working fine. But now any user from the client machine can *Push*, *Pull* and *Clone*. I want to make an authentication mechanism which asks the users to enter their user name and password before doing any of the previous operations. I added allow_push = *username* in the hgweb.config. Now  when the client *Push* Tortoise Hg (version 2.5) is asking for username and pass word. I think the username will be the user name that I entered in the hgweb.config. But I have no idea about the password which Tortoise Hg asks after submitting the username. How can I set password for the users? Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something from the [tutorial you had followed](http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/02/24/running-a-mercurial-server-on-iis-7-5-windows-server-2008-r2):

> Pushing another test will result in Mercurial asking for a username and password, authenticated against the domain.

This means that the password is the password for the user's domain account in your setup.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Can you please give a brief explanation about the user's domain account.I can't find it.

Comment: You'll have to use the section "Authentication and Authorisation" as a starting point. I am not so familiar with configuring IIS. Google is your friend :)